# Systemd ExecStartPre getting variables before ExecStart on next line

Tags: 16.04, upstart, systemd

on Systemd I would like to execute following command which works fine on shell manually:

```
/usr/bin/company_program --init.d `/usr/bin/lua -l company_exec -e 'dofile("/etc/company_profiles"); print(table.concat(company_exec.table_to_companyexec_argv(default), " "))'`
```

How could I transfer it to ExecStartPre which runs:

```
/usr/bin/lua -l company_exec -e 'dofile("/etc/company_profiles"); print(table.concat(company_exec.table_to_companyexec_argv(default), " "))'
```

Then feed the result to ExecStart which runs:

```
/usr/bin/company_program --init.d `${previous_execstartpre_lua_result}`
```

Comment: On mobile but I believe `export` will help in this issue

Comment: On mobile but I believe `export` will help in this issue. Pass the output into a variable then export that.

Comment: mind to give an answer when you back to your desktop please? Thanks!

Comment: I have tried to create such a systemd service but unfortunately isn't so your best bet will be to write a script with those commands and call it from systemd service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both lines into a script and run it from a single `ExecStart=` command.

Comment: put into a script works, may I know why I can't include it without script?

Comment: The behavior is documented in `man systemd.service` in the "Command Lines" section. As it says there "...   This syntax is intended to be very similar to shell syntax, but only the meta-characters and expansions described in the following paragraphs are understood.... ".  It's possible to set an environment variable that is read in by a later bash command.  See https://gist.github.com/nickjacob/9909574

Comment: I see, so there are limitations imposed on ExecStart, Thanks